# Http call won't send cookies

Tags: angular, google-chrome, http, cookies

I have an angular application (port 4200) and a flask python backend (port 8080) which are both running and communicating on localhost.
Since I had problems setting cookies which the backend needed, I adjusted the /etc/hosts file and added the domain for both applications:

```
127.0.0.1       app.localhost.com
127.0.0.1       server.localhost.com
```

After that I could successfully set the cookies but the angular application which I am accessing with the app.localhost.com url still won't send the cookies with the request (see pics).

I tried to set the cookie in the frontend when loading the app:

```
document.cookie = 'test' + '=' + 'access' + ';domain=localhost.com; path=/';
```

And I tried to set the cookie as an api call in the backend

```
@application.route("/api/v1/cookies")
def set_cookie_role():
    resp = make_response('Set cookie', 200)
    resp.set_cookie('test', '12345', domain='localhost.com')
    return resp
```

[image: Cookie which should be sent]
[image: Request without Cookie which has been set]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the domain for the cookie in the app as

> localhost.com

instead of `.localhost.com` so that `app.localhost.com` being a subdomain can pickup the cookie of the domain.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox do add the '.' at the beginning of the domain automatically so I somehow can't set the domain to localhost.com
I added the code to my question

Comment: can you post the code that sets the cookie in the response header to the browser

Comment: The browser would send the cookies which are part of the domain with every request why should I set them in the header of the request?

Comment: @DarioDigregorio, I  was checking with you on the code to set the cookie in the **response** not on the *request*

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but I edited my question with code that used to set the cookie in the backend as a respond and in the frontend as a request